# SEHExceptions/ConfigurationErrorsExceptions in DbProviderFactories

Tags: c#

I have been searching for some answers for at least 3 hours now and I have not found anything.
I'll note that this USED to work and nothing has been touched in terms of the SQL server or the Visual Studio side.

Emulating a server that has two servers; one that controls the main server and one that controls the access/base (logins and initial connection). 
They used to be able to access the database and using the udl I confirmed the connection with user/pass being correct.

```
public Database(string connectionString, string providerName)
{
    _factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName); // This throws the exception(s)
    _com = _factory.CreateCommand();
    _con = _factory.CreateConnection();
    _con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    _com.Connection = _con;
}
```

The exceptions are:

```
External Component has thrown an exception (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException)

A System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException has occurred
An Error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data: 
External Component has thrown an exception
```

And the config is

```
<add name="Database"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=True;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Like I said this used to work and nothing has been changed. The only exception being Windows Update.

I searched both of these errors, the ConfigurationErrorsException had only said that the config was wrong - but the config hasn't changed since last working build. 
And the SEHException might as well have been Microsoft saying that they themselves do not know.

If anyone has had this issue recently or in the past, it would be great if they could help... Even if it is not related to the issue but has had the same exceptions/outcome.

Comment: Before anyone came to say anything I went to check previous versions and they are acting the same. Would this be a framework issue?

Comment: No one able to help? At least before i reformat just on the off chance that windows update to 4.6 has rearranged libraries as it does